# Unable to change gnome-terminal default character encoding

Tags: gnome-terminal, encoding, character-set

I have tried everything that I could find on the internet.

```
$> gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/encoding "en_US.UTF-8"

$> cat /etc/environment
...
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

$> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
...
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But whenever I open a new gnome-terminal, my powerline symbols still show up as question marks, and Terminal->Set Character Encoding is set to "Current Locale (ANSI3.4-1968)" which I then change to UTF-8 manually and then things are fine.

I have already rebooted the system multiple times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this done! Noting the answer here just in case someone else stumbles upon here with an ancient OS :)

1. Open `gconf-editor`. Search for `encoding` in keys and values. Specifically look for `/apps/gnome-terminal/global/active_encodings`. And change the value to `"UTF-8"` (it's a list of strings type, just keep one item in the list)
2. In your startup file (.bashrc or .cshrc), export environment variable `LC_ALL` to `"en_US.UTF-8"` (if you are in the USA) and reboot the system!

I did both the things above. Not sure which one exactly fixes it. Most likely only #1 might be needed. But good idea to set locale properly anyway.

Hope this helps someone. I figured this out by trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Gnome terminal use UTF-8 by default, but if you need to enable other encodings you can do so from Edit -> Preferences -> Encodings.[image]

Or in dconf at the path `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/encodings`.  This allows you to change it programatically using `gesttings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings encodings "['UTF-8']"
```